# How to stop “pop out” in embedded video with <iframe> from google drive. I want to change the over-layer color but unable to do

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code.The color of the layer is not changing. So, what I have to do?

```
<div  style="width: 640px; height: 480px; position: relative;">
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxLbnVHP6GWpV2ZIZEc4SkNTOTQ/preview"   width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" seamless=""></iframe>
    <div style="width: 80px; height: 80px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; right: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: #FF0000;"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What color should something with `opacity: 0` have?

Comment: @Coders Corner Try to make  `border: 1px solid black; `, put  `opacity: 1;} ` and tell us what happend :)

Comment: should i have to remove opacity ??